# Could not create database `mydb` for connection named default An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver

Tags: windows, phpmyadmin, wamp, symfony6

Could not create database `mydb` for connection named default An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver

## DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"

## DATABASE_URL="mysql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:3306/app?serverVersion=8&charset=utf8mb4"

DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?serverVersion=8"
#DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###